# Mwaa airflow task skipping

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I am trying to create a ml training mwaa airflow workflow
I have below steps

1. Data processing
2. Training
3. Batch inference

My requirement is to run data processing and inference every week and training in every month.

How can I skip training step and make it run only once in month

Comment: Yiu can make 2 different dags. One for inference and one for training and schedule each one accordingly

Comment: You can use a ShortCircuitOperator to accomplish this. It can call a python function to determine whether to run the training tasks or not, and the function can check the `data_interval_start` to make sure it only runs once per month. Docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.ShortCircuitOperator